# Get server error: "The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations" ans simple solutios don't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, deployment, hosting

I've created my site and it is work fine in my local system, but when I download it to server I get this error:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

At first look it is easy. Server say me that I don't have specified files, but there is 
Views\Home\Index.cshtml file in my hosting folder! And as I said before it is work fine in my local system. Also I have controller with Home name.

This is my route config:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And this is [link to the site](http://www.zb.somee.com/).

Comment: Have you checked that the files have been correctly copied to your development server

Comment: Yes, you was right. It is very strange. I publish site to local folder and there is all files. But when I copy it to server via FTP there is no my View files. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem:
I publish site to local folder and there is all files. But when I copy it to server via FTP there is no my View files.
Sorry for extra question!

Answer (score 1):

You check with `MVC` versions between provider `server` and in your `development` environment. Then you need to upgrade or downgrade the version as *same* on both.

Comment: I use Asp.Net MVC 4 in my project and .Net 4, but my hosting provider allow to specify only Asp.Net version(so I also specify 4 version). Is version of Asp.Net and Asp.Net MVC is matches?

Comment: `MVC` versions need to match between server and development.